# php sending double email

Tags: php, email

I realize that this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531892/phpmailer-duplicate-email-issue-conditional-statement-with-mail-send), however, I only get a double email when sending to myself. I have sent emails to others with the same script, and they get a single email. This is the email script:

```
<?php
  function sendEmail( $recipient, $sub, $msg )
  {
    $to      = $recipient;
    $subject = $sub;
    $message = $msg;

    mail( $to, $subject, $message );
  }
?>
```

The code calling this is this:

```
if( $retVal != FALSE ) // No errors in execution of report generation
{
  $subject = "Successful Report";
  $message = "The report was successfully generated.";
  // Notify people about success
  sendEmail( $mailto, $subject, $message );

  echo "Successful report generation\n";
}
else // Error in report generation
{
  $subject = "Unsuccessful Report";
  $message = "The report failed to generate.";
  // Notify people about failure
  sendEmail( $mailto, $subject, $message );

  echo "Report generation was unsuccessful\n";
}
```

where $retval is the return value of [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php). Can anyone shed some light on this issue? Or is this something that can be overlooked?

Thanks very much

-rusty

Comment: Is the email to yourself perhaps an alias that sends to multiple email addresses that you receive?  Do you receive a copy of emails sent to others?  If so, perhaps you are seeing the one to yourself and the copy to yourself.

Comment: Is it possible that the error is with the MTA? Can you confirm that a block of code is running twice, or are you only getting double the result?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using a (B)CC in the Email header?

Comment: Another thing to check is the Message ID in the header of the two emails you get. Are they identical?

Comment: @EricJ. I do not get a copy of email sent to others

Comment: @AaronDougherty I believe that the code is running only once because the message to terminal is printing only once

Comment: your sendEmail function is being called conditionally so it will either run in the if statement or the else statement..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the conversation: You are the only recipient that is receiving double email, and the string "Successful report generation" only prints once. It sounds like PHP is not the culprit here, rather something outside of PHP, such as the MTA.

Take a look at the headers of the two email you receive, particularly the MessageID header. If they are identical, then a single email was sent from PHP (good!) and somewhere along the line it got delivered to you twice.

If they are not identical (messy), then PHP did in fact send out two emails (not likely) or there is a resender somewhere between PHP and your mail client.

In the later case, I would take a deeper look at the headers in your email, to determine the source and route of each email, as well as the envelope to determine where the MTA though it was sending mail to.

Comment: The two headers are in fact identical. Thank you

Comment: How would I go about solving this issue? Or should I just leave it alone?

Comment: I would say it's pretty safe to leave it alone, aside from the annoyance factor. Because the headers are identical, that means that at some point after the email was sent by PHP, the email was sent to multiple recipients, two of which are you. This is often the case if the email address that PHP is using is actually an alias, or a mailing list. In the end, it looks like your application is working, and the problem is not with PHP, or your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would add the output from [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) into the body of your email. This will allow you to determine when the `sendEmail` function is called and who called it.

Comment: The output seems to indicate that there is only one call to sendEmail. It shows the array containing the call to the original function and then to the email function

Comment: The other question, are they both the same MIME type? HTML vs Plaintext?

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = "";
$header = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;\r\n";
mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Comment: I am rather new to PHP. Could you explain what your header does?

Comment: @bcrusty your sendEmail function is being called conditionally so it will either run in the if statement or the else statement..