# PHPMailer sending identical duplicate emails to only 1 recipient every time

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a very simple script that sends a periodic email from the server to confirm that everything is working ok.  The email is sent to only one address and every time, two identical emails are sent.There are no loops, no database calls for additional addresses.  Everything is set and fixed in the script.

There are a ton of similar questions on this topic.  All deal with a slightly different situation - adding addresses, occasional duplicates, etc. - and I've carefully followed the advice in each. I've also followed the advice of @Synchro to read the PHPMailer docs carefully. Specifically I have:

- simplified the interactions down to the simplest code - forget the chron job, forget gathering the data for the email, etc. (see below)
- upgraded to the latest version of PHPMailer
- looked for use of $mail->send() in a conditional statement per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531892/phpmailer-duplicate-email-issue-conditional-statement-with-mail-send) (could not find any)
- turned Apache's rewrite engine off, thinking that a possible server redirect was duplicating the request (and restarted server)
- used firebug to detect duplicate get requests for the page (only one request is shown)
- disabled all plugins and extensions in firefox and restarted firefox
- tried the same script in Chrome
- set the debug notice level for smtp to 1; nothing earth shattering here, the script runs once
- compared the email Message-IDs.  The Message-ID in the smtp debug message and BOTH emails are identical
- moved relevant scripts to different dev environment

In every case I get the same result - 2 identical emails get sent with the same Message-IDs with exactly the same time stamp.

The simplified **test_send_mail.php** calling script:

```
$subject = 'TEST PHP_MAILER';
$msg = 'this is only a test';
$mail = new send_mail('','',$subject,$msg);
$mail->send_it();
exit('sent');
```

The **send_mail** class looks like this:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/phpMail_core.php');

set_include_path('c:/Apache24/Core/_common/PHPMailer-master/');
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
require 'class.smtp.php';

class send_mail {

    //__CONSTRUCT
    function __construct($to='',$from='',$subject='[no subject]',$body='[no content]') {
        if(empty($to)) {
            $to = DEFAULT_RECIPIENT;
        }

        if(empty($from)) {
            $from = SYS_ADMIN;
        }

        $this->ready_mail = $this->set_parameters($to,$from,$subject,$body);

    }

    // SET_PARAMETERS
    function set_parameters($to,$from,$subject,$body) {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // true = throw exceptions on errors

        $mail->IsSMTP();          

        try {
            $mail->clearAddresses();
            $mail->Host = SMTP_SERVER; 
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;       //0 = none; 1 = some; 2 = all
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT;        
            $mail->Username = SMTP_USERNAME;
            $mail->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD;
            //for php5.6 to bypass SSL check
            $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );

            $mail->WordWrap = 50;   
            $mail->isHTML(true);        // Set email format             

            $mail->SetFrom($from);
            $mail->FromName = 'UHMS SysAdmin';
            $mail->addAddress($to);
            //for local only
            $mail->Subject = $subject.' *local*';
            //for production only
            //$mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = $body;


        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
            pp('phpMailerException',$e->errorMessage());

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            pp('send_mail exception',$e->getMessage());
        }

        return $mail;       
    }

    //SEND_IT
    function send_it() {

        echo '<br>sending...';
        $this->ready_mail->Send();          

    }
```

**PHPMail_core.php** simply defines the default values (CAPITALIZED_TERMS) used in the send_mail class, nothing more.

The environment is: PHP 7.0.13/PHPMailer 5.2.21/Apache 2.4.23

What else could possibly be causing the duplicate emails?

Comment: It is bad practice to have a constructor which also performs some action i.e. `$mail->Send();`. You should move that call to a new member function of the `send_mail` class and then call that function from your `$mail` instance.

Comment: Thanks for reading the docs  ! Is it sending 2 copies of the exact same message, or 2 separate messages? One way to test for that is to check message IDs, or append a random number to the subject line. Also enable `SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see exactly what's going to your mail server. That class has a very odd structure, sending from the constructor like that - though I don't see anything that would stop it working.

Comment: @Synchro - as noted above, it is two identical emails with the same Message-ID - i.e., they are carbon copies of each other - no differences.

Comment: And how does it look in debug output, and in your mail server logs?

Comment: @Synchro - the SMTP output looks very normal - one and only one pass through AUTH LOGIN, Authentication succeeded, all the message stuff, then QUIT.   As for mail logs, where would those be?  The email account is on a hosted server.

Comment: @Michael - revised the code above and ran it.  Still 2 emails.

Comment: As you are not setting a `$to`, where and to what is `DEFAULT_RECIPIENT` set?

Comment: @JBES it is set to the address at which I am receiving the duplicate emails. It is defined as the DEFAULT_RECIPIENT in the PHPMail_core.php file.

Comment: Do you get duplicates if you send elsewhere, like to a gmail account? If you're only logging one send, but receiving two, it must be happening in your mail server.

Comment: @Synchro - I think you are zeroing in on the problem.  In parallel to this SO post, I opened a ticket with my hosting company and they've looked into things.  The email logs all show only one email being sent/received.  They too suggested sending to a different account.  So I set up a brand new test email account and changed the DEFAULT_RECIPIENT to this account.  Lo and behold only one email was delivered!  So the hypothesis is that my email client - Thunderbird - is the culprit and this has nothing to do with PHPMailer or my script.  Still doing a few things to confirm this...

Comment: I also noted later in the day that my iPhone and iPad only received one email - no duplicates - further lending credence that this is a Thunderbird client issue somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the bottom line is that the phenomenon described above was totally caused by an "operator error". Sometime in the past, I had set up an email filter rule in cPanel for the recipient email account.  The rule effectively caused a duplicate delivery of this particular email.  It's weird that I wasn't getting duplicates of other emails, but indeed, as soon as the offending rule was removed, the duplicate emails described above ceased...and all emails seem to be coming through just fine. So the root cause had nothing to do with PHPMailer, the hosting company, Thunderbird or the code.

The filter rule was created long ago and far away so wasn't the obvious cause. I'm memorializing the conclusion here just in case it helps.  Let it be proof that the tracks you lay can sometimes lead you in the wrong direction...

Totally appreciate all the help provided by others in getting to this embarrassing conclusion.